# Mongo Db parents and children tags related to other collections fields

Tags: php, mongodb, object, nosql

Well , i'm going to set up my mongo db schema for a little site, what i need is to reproduce this schema into mongo db collections:

```
product
        -> tag1
              ->child_tag1
              ->child_tag2
        -> tag2
              ->child_tag1
              ->child_tag2
        -> tag3
              ->child_tag1
              ->child_tag2
```

which is the best way to reproduce this schema with mongo ?

For sure i need to be able to change a tag or child tag without update all collection objects :)
[EDITED]

Well cause of i know my question is not so clear, i need to clarify that i'm trying converting a mysql db site onto a mongoDb site.

So i have 4 tables in mysql:

```
products

id(AUTO) | product_name | qty
 1          biscuits      34
 2          limonade      29

tags

id(AUTO) |  tag_name 
  1            sugar
  2            eggs
  3            vitamine C

tags_childs

id(AUTO) | id_tag | tag_child_name
  1          1        glucouse
  2          2        protein
  3          2        chicken
products_tags

id_product | id_tag | id_tag_child 
  1            1         NULL
  1            1         1
  1            2         3
  2            3        NULL
```

so i use products_tags table to join over 4 tables (and this is why heating joins i'm switching to mongoDb :))

so i can reproduce this scenario with mongodb collections and objects?

thx :)

Comment: can you explain a bit more on what exactly you're doing? as right now I'm not fully understanding what exactly you're doing.

Comment: So a completely separate issue which i'd like to point out.. I'm not certain but you shouldn't need both a tags and tags_childs table as you could just have an extra column in tags labeled "tag_parent_id", which is an id of another tag.. Drafting up an answer to the question at hand though, but at least wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to make sure I'm understanding what your above document shows; essentially Many Products can have Many Tags, and Tags can have children under them (Coding tag -> Php is child tag of Coding).

With that being my understanding of the above question here's how I would structure your Mongo Collections:

Products Collection:

```
{
   "ProductName":"Sweet Jelly",
   "Qty":9,
   "Tags":[
     ListOfTagIds
    ]
 }
```

The list of TagIds would be the Unique Identifiers which mongoDB automatically assigns to each of the new fields created.. [see here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs)

From there I'd create a Tags Collection:

```
{
  "TagName":"Coding Languages";
  "ChildTags":[
      $_idOfChildren
   ]
}
```

Then if your tag had a child:

```
{ 
  "TagName":"PHP",
}
```

For this Parent / Child relationship you can read a bit more about it from this excellent mongo resource located here: [Mongo Book](http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf) - Page 16 starting with No Joins.

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for links they are really interesting :) , sorry but i removed acceptation on answer, cause (maybe my bad question not clear for sure), i need a 1-to-many-to-many relationship , cause products can have many parent tags themself related to many childs tags , so if product has parent tag 1 he can have no tag 1 childs tags related , don't know if clear  ... sorry for my bad english

Comment: trying planning what i sad, product { _id:ObjectId(), tags:[id_tag_parent:[id_tag_child,id_tag_child,id_tag_child],id_tag_parent:[NULL cause i need it can be NULL],id_tag_parent:[id_tag_child] ] }

Comment: uhm ... :P i edited my question up :P better if you check out my table data :P eheh thx!

Comment: So you can do this still; however instead of looking for a parent you could change it to use children id's.  See my edit.