# Mongo DB best practice for a query WHERE IN with tags and childs

Tags: mongodb, collections, tags, schema, nosql

Well i'm planning a collection schema and i have dubt to how embed data inside tag field.

i have a colletion named products:

```
products
       ->_id
       ->product_name
       ->tags
```

i have then a tags collection:

```
tags
    ->_id
    ->tag_name
```

and i have a tags_child collection:

```
tags_childs
      ->_id
      -> id_tag
      ->tag_child_name
```

now i need to save tags and tags_childs into products collection, so i tought it was good to save in products collection a field:

tags: [[_id_tag]:[_id_tag_child,_id_tag_child, ... etc],[_id_tag]:[_id_tag_child,_id_tag_child, ... etc]]

but i think is not the right way, cause i need to be able to query on products collection, filtering by tags and child_tags.

So for example i need to filter products by:
+product_name: 'roastbeef' 
 + tag:'hot' 
  + child tag : 'sauce'

or filter by:
+product_name: 'roastbeef' 
 + tag: 'hot' 
   + child tag:'sauce' 
    + child tag:'knife'
 + tag:'dinner'

Parent tags are always required when filtering, while child tags are optional.

How do you implement a right collection to do this type of query at the end?

Comment: I don't understand the parent/child tag concept. Tags are tags. If you want to make a mandatory/optional filter just add a "optional: true" field to the original tag document. No need to have two collections.

Comment: did you merging tags and child tags collections? sorry i edited my answer i missed up 1 field in child tags collection

Comment: the problem is that product can have a tag but can not have a tag child , so i think i need to separate them into two different collections, not ? :P

Comment: The concept of tags is to decorate your objects, products in this case, with labels that can be used for search filters (e.g. "red", "heavy"). Give us an example of the difference between a tag and a child tag that illustrates why this does not suffice.

Comment: ok .. first of all not only products have tags and tags childs, i can have also a new collection named "services" , so services and products shares same tags and related child tags, but services is not parent or child of products (they are two different collections)  .   Then a tag can be 'Wine' and 'Wine' tag childs could be 'red','white'.  Now product for example can have 'Wine' but can NOT have 'white'

Comment: then at the end i will need to be able to filter products by Wine + red or by just only 'Wine'

Comment: at same time i will need to be able to filter also services by 'Wine' or by 'Wine' and child 'red'

Comment: I don't think you understand tags. The whole point is to have a "wine" tag and a "red" tag and then you can simply search "wine, red" to find all red wines. Having a "red wine" tag completely defeats the purpose of tags. That's categorization not tagging.

Comment: yep you're right what i'm trying to do it's categorization by tags, and i don't know how to extends collections :(

Comment: is as tags are categories and child tags are subcategories :)

Comment: Alright, it helps people answer if you use the appropriate terms ;) Since (sub)categorization is a hierarchical structure it's slightly less straightforward to implement but still should only have one category collection with an optional parentId if it is a child.

Comment: what you think about adding 2 fields in products collection like :  product{  tags: [id_tag,id_tag,id_tag] , tags_childs:[id_tag_child,id_tag_child]} ... definitely i think is the best way to categorize, but i'm afraid i will lost parent and childs relation uhm... really hard for me %) ...

Comment: From this answer here.. you shouldn't have extra collection of your many to many relationship: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390574/mongo-db-parents-and-childs-tags-related-to-other-collections-fileds  Schema isn't inforced with NoSQL db's so you shouldn't need to do these many to many pivotal tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading over this; I described your schema a bit in detail here:

- [Schema Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390574/mongo-db-parents-and-childs-tags-related-to-other-collections-fileds)

There really isn't a reason to be holding this pivotal table, as in the end they are all just tags. You can still search for multiple tags within your database by going with the above suggested schema; along with showing all your available tags to and their relationship from the above schema; this way it cleans up your entire DB rather than muddying it with an extra table which MongoDB just doesn't need.

I'd highly recommend re-going through this e-book to just strengthen the understanding around the NoSQL format Mongo empowers you with.

- [Mongo Free eBook PDF](http://openmymind.net/mongodb_cover.png)

Comment: No problem; it can really be a big adjustment from using something like MySQL, but once you get the hang of it; it's just awesome!

Comment: yep i hope and i think too :)!